# How do I create a QueryTimeframe using the keen-sdk-net package?

Tags: .net, keen-io

I’m looking at using the [.NET SDK](https://github.com/keenlabs/keen-sdk-net), and I am trying a test query. I am having trouble creating a QueryTimeframe for say the last 30 minutes. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the `QueryRelativeTimeframe` class, like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var keenClient = new KeenClient(new ProjectSettingsProviderEnv());

    // create an event to query
    //keenClient.AddEvent("ACollection", new { AProperty = "AValue" });

    // query the event
    var result = keenClient.QueryExtractResource("ACollection", QueryRelativeTimeframe.PreviousNMinutes(30)).ToList();
    if (result.Any())
        Console.WriteLine(result.First());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("No matching records");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

However, there was a small bug in PreviousNMinutes relative timeframe query, you would have gotten an error back from the server due to a formatting error. I've pushed an update, you can pull it from github or update with Nuget to v0.3.7.